# Acumatica Report Designer, Conditional Output

Tags: report, conditional-statements, acumatica

In the Acumatica Report Designer, I want to conditionally populate a field for a single Order Type based on the content of a single custom field in the same screen.

Below is an image of the field I want to base the condition on:

[image]

In Report Designer, this custom field is accessible via [SOOrder.UserDocumentStatus] similar to other fields.
[image]

An example of how I want to do this with the Title of the report: if the Doc Status is "Order Confirmation" then the Title field will say "Order Confirmation" and if Doc Status says "Regular" it will say "Regular" in the same label.

Below is a dump of some functions I thought might be useful:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do it using an IIf statement for each option, which is the same as using the Switch function (but I did this before actually knowing how the switch works and still find it easier to follow)

```
=iif([SOOrder.DocStatus]=='Regular', 'Regular', '') +
iif([SOOrder.DocStatus]=='Factory Order', 'Factory Order', '') +
iif([SOOrder.DocStatus]=='Order Confirmation', 'Order Confirmation', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Note .DocStatus is a guess at the name of the custom field in the DAC you should be able to select it from the fields drop down in the expression builder.

```
IIf([SOOrder.DocStatus] == 'Regular', 'Regular', 'Value if False')
```

If you wanted to test the whole selection use the switch

```
Switch( [SOOrder.DocStatus] == 'Regular', 'Regular', [SOOrder.DocStatus] == 'Factory Order', 'Factory Order', ...)
```

You may have to swap out the == for just = I cant remember exactly how the report designer handles string equality at the moment. And the "" vs '' (Use '' I think thats the right way) is also something to swap if it doesnt work the first time.